# How to enable SSL for both Apache2 and Jetty Server

Tags: ssl, apache2, jetty

I am new to SSL. I got apache2 running, which hosts my personal website,
and also a jetty server via proxy pass (ProxyPass /abc http://{local host}:8080/abc).

How can I enable SSL for both Apache2 and Jetty?

Comment: Here's the documenation on how to configure ssl in jetty 9:
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a nice howto to configure apache2 using https. http://mrfoo.de/archiv/347-Howto-Apache2-SSL-Zertifikat-erstellen-und-aktivieren.html

The Jetty can run with http (as long as you block the 8080 Port from outside with your firewall. Then use proxy pass to pass requests to http://:8080/

Her's an example vhost config:

```
# Force HTTPS only (proxy to port 443)
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.mydomain.lan
    RewriteEngine on
    ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>

# HTTPS requests Proxy to tomcat/jetty 
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName app.mydomain.lan
    ServerSignature Off
    ProxyRequests Off
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/myssl/server.cert.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/myssl/server.cert.crt

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/ retry=1
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyVia On
</VirtualHost>
```